# Frame corner radius not rounding corners on iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to round the corners of a stack layout, it works on android but on iOS, they still appear square but it does display the Frame shadow

My XAML is

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="WHITE">
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    . . .
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Any ideas? I need to find the fix to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> they still appear square

Actually, the `Frame` is round not the `StackLayout`, we just use Frame wrap it ,so it looks the StackLayout has round corners.

#### Frame

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="Red">
    <StackLayout >
         <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

[image]

#### StackLayout

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" HasShadow="False" >
   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
         <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
   </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

[image]

> it does display the Frame shadow

You can disable it by `HasShadow="False"`.

Comment: The problem is it's not wrapping the corners it's displaying square on iOS but Android its round

Comment: @Dan see the screenshot.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT I believe it is workaround but not a solution, if you are developing a cross-platform app. See my answer below.

Answer (score 16):

Set `IsClippedToBounds` property to Frame control:

```
<Frame IsClippedToBounds="True" CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10">
    <StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I believe, it is a bug of Xamarin.Forms. UWP, Android and iOS should behave the same, but they don't. As a result to implement the same behaviour developers need to use OnPlatform feature.

The bug is described and discussed here, it is still open: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2405