# How to make frame contents respect its corner radius?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have different elements, controls and views wrapped in frames in order to apply corner radius, which is working fine on Android. But on the iOS side, even though the frame is round cornered, its contents does not clip to its radius but stays square as if nothing is applied.

**Sample:-**

```xml
<Frame BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Theme}" CornerRadius="15" Padding="0">
    <Image Source="{Binding PImage}" HeightRequest="132.5" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
</Frame>
```

Expected (Which happens in Android):-

[image: Expected Result]

Actual:-

[image: Actual Result]

How to make the frame contents respect the corner radius like what happens in Android ?

Comment: try set the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` of the Frame instead of the image, also try to set the `Padding` of the frame to 1. If after that still doesn't work propertly wrap the Frame in a StackLayout.

Comment: I tried them all, setting the height and width request, padding or wrapping the frame inside if a StackLayout. All didn't work... This is turning to be really weird...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Frame corner radius not rounding corners on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092008/frame-corner-radius-not-rounding-corners-on-ios)

Answer (score 3):

Clip the content of the frame to its boundaries:

```
<StackLayout Padding="30">
    <Frame CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
        <Image Source="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55611485/1039935

[image]

Comment: Even though it looked promising, but after I tried it, same thing exactly, the content was not clipped...

Answer (score 0):

From shared code works in my local site :

[image]

The sample **solution** : Have a check with the version of **Visual Studio** and **Xamarin Forms** .Be sure that have updated to the latest version (*Visual Studio: `16.6.5`, Xamarin Forms : `4.7.0.1239`*).

**Otherwise** , you can create a [Custom Frame Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) in iOS to set `CornerRadius` .

Create a **CustomFrame** :

```
public class CustomFrame: Frame
{
}
```

Create a Custom renderer in iOS:

```
public class CustomFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Layer.CornerRadius = Element.CornerRadius;
        //Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
        Layer.MasksToBounds = true;

    }
}
```

In **Xaml** use the custom Renderer :

```
<local:CustomFrame BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"
        Padding="0">
    <Image Source="XamarinLogo.png"
            HeightRequest="132.5"
            Aspect="AspectFill" />
</local:CustomFrame>
```

Comment: I'm not experienced with custom renders, so is there a way to make the custom render extend the regular frame element on ios only without the usage of custom frame?

Comment: @MohamedAshraf I'm not sure . I will check whether it is possible . Could you share the version of Visual Studio and Xamarin Froms ? In the latest version , the shared code works also in iOS .

Comment: I'm using the latest VS and Xamarin versions... But I don't really know how to make it work...

Comment: @MohamedAshraf Okey , it's strange. Could you share a sample project link here ? I want to check that in my local site to see what happens.